# Apps added to App Catalog not available for installation on other sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx-webparts

I started with SPFx development recently. I packaged a client side web-part as a file **helloworld-webpart.sppkg** following Microsoft's tutorial. Then I uploaded it to my Apps Catalog site. Though it was uploaded to the Apps Catalog successfully, but it's not available for installation on any of the sites. I tried the gear 'Add an App', tried searching for 'helloworld', but couldn't find it.

Any suggestion/help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was with my webpart code. I were getting this error before packaging the webpart:

-> **Cannot find module 'helloWorldStrings'**

I removed this error first, then again packaged the solution and uploaded it to the Apps Catalog site. This time it is working fine as expected.

Comment: Hi, Plz accept your own answer as answer. So the question will not be part of unanswered questions list.

Comment: Oops answer accepted!

Comment: I did not get this error anywhere. In what file did you fix the module name?

Comment: In HelloWorldWebPart.ts file, I had this error.