# SPFx web part not showing from the catalog

Tags: 2016, spfx-webparts

Followed the video from

[SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)

but could not add the web part to the site because it did not show up.
I made sure I have only SPFx 1.0.2 is installed.
I know the catalog is working because other apps from the store do show.

Is there a detailed walkthrough to make sure all the moving part on SP2016 FP2 are correctly installed?

Any other walkthrough recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem in past. And were able to resolve it in the following way:

The problem was with my webpart code. I were getting this error before packaging the webpart:

-> **Cannot find module 'helloWorldStrings'**

I removed this error first, then again packaged the solution and uploaded it to the Apps Catalog site. This time it was working fine as expected. Check the following post for reference:

[Check this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224121/apps-added-to-app-catalog-not-available-for-installation-on-other-sites)

Hope that helps you as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/82747)

Comment: Essential parts included!

Comment: This does not answer my question. I did not see any error

Comment: Please be careful first you need to compile the code using the command 'GULP'. If it gets compiled successfully that means it the package has no error. I have already mentioned in my case it had certain error and I wasn't able to deploy the correct package successfully in the Apps catalog!